# Vim Can't Delete on MacOS

Tags: macos

I'm using vim 8.2.3017 built from source (the build version is not important since whatever version I use there exists this problem) on MacOS.

The problem in brief: I can only delete characters inserted the current insert session (each time I press `i` or `a`)

Say that I have a file `test.txt` already containing the word `test`. When I open this file by `vim test.txt` and try to delete any letter after pressing `a` or `i`, Mac refuses to remove the letter and sometimes produces a 'dung' sound. As a result, I can only delete characters by using `x` or `d` under normal mode.

Now I want to insert the word `example`, but I accidentally inserted `examplw`. I press delete - and then the `w` disappears! But when I remove the whole word `example`, I cannot delete more.

Then I save the file by typing `:w` in the command. Say that I want to delete the word `example` now. But I cannot delele it.

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably set `:h 'backspace'` option:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Where `start` is the one that lets you delete over start of insert pos.

Check the others in the help description.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: Same for me on Mac OS Monterrey